# Add a validation in dynamic action in apex

Tags: validation, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am creating a desk reservation application in apex, I have a page to select the date and time for a specific desk and I have an apply button to run the plsql code to insert the data in the reservation table in the db. Now, I want to validate if  for the selected desk there is not any other reservation in the same date and in the same time range, then the reservation will be booked.I have created a hidden page item as a flag, and then 2 true actions before the action of inserting data:

first true action : Execute Server Side code

```
  BEGIN

    :P6_DUPLICATE_FLAG := 'N';

    FOR ITEM in (SELECT TIME_TO FROM WPB_RESERVATIONS WHERE RESERVATION_DATE = 
     :P6_RESERVATION_DATE
                                                        AND LOC_ID = :P6_LOC_ID 
                                                        AND ROOM_ID = :P6_ROOM_ID
                                                        AND WORKPLACE_ID = 
      :P6_WORKPLACE_ID)
    LOOP
        IF ITEM.TIME_TO > :P6_TIME_FROM THEN   
           :P6_DUPLICATE_FLAG := 'Y' ;
    
        END IF;
    END LOOP;  
  END;
```

and the second true action :Execute java-script code

```
// First clear the errors
apex.message.clearErrors();

var errorFlag= $v('P6_DUPLICATE_FLAG');

if(errorFlag == 'Y') {
// Now show new errors
apex.message.showErrors([
{
    type:       "error",
    location:   [ "page", "inline" ],
    message:    "There is a reservation for this desk in selected time!",
    unsafe:     false
}
]); 
//To stop the further actions from firing
apex.da.cancelEvent.call(this);
 }
```

the problem is I get different errors when pressing the apply buttun even the date is correct and I am sure it is not duplicated.
before adding this validation everything worked ok.
Am I doing something wrong?
IS there any other way to do this validation?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a dynamic action and not a validation ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was very complicated and I've done that with Ajax Callback.